# Gradle TransitiveDependency Version Conflict

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, pdfbox

I've been implementing an extending pdf-creation API for an existing project using PDFBox. 
In order to use PDFBox I need to include following dependency in my build.gradle:

```
implementation('com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.0')
```

One of the dependencies the existing project is using is spongycastle for crypto components:

```
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.58.0.0'
```

So I first included both dependencies to my build.gradle file and
tried to build the application. This is the exception I'm receiving:

> Program type already present:
>   org.spongycastle.cert.CertRuntimeException Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   org.spongycastle.cert.CertRuntimeException, sources=[Unknown source
>   file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I assumed this problem occurs because of a version conflict due to transitive dependencies of pdfbox, which are the following:
[image]

I tried to solve the problem using the dependency-exclude in my build.gradle:

```
implementation('com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.0'){
exclude group:'com.madgag.spongycastle'
}
```

Because, as far as i know, I'm not using crypto aspects directly in my pdfbox implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot - I've been able to solve the problem using a different approach.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0') with module('com.madgag.spongycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.58.0.0')
    }
}
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [force predefined versions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
        force 'com.magdag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'
        force 'com.magdag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
    }
}
```

It might also a change in libraries due to versions. Maybe a deleted or renamed file. You can also try to force 1.54.0.0 versions